# Incorrect backgroundTimeRemaining value in applicationDidEnterBackground method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a Objective C project on Xcode6 beta 2 running on an iOS8 device. I am printing the backgroundTimeRemaining in the method: **applicationDidEnterBackground**.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog:(@"Background time remaining %f seconds", application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
  NSLog:(@"Background time remaining %f seconds", application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
  NSLog:(@"Background time remaining %f seconds", application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
}
```

The results I received were:

179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000 seconds

9.995252 seconds

9.991967 seconds

Why does it output this big value on the first log (1797693...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out a quick and dirty fix that seems to work. Make the thread sleep a bit before requesting applicationTimeRemaning:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.01];
  NSLog:(@"Background time remaining %f seconds", application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
}
```

But this is obviously not an ideal solution.

Comment: old post, but I think the answer is because the background task (entering the background) really has not registered as active yet, it will just return the lifespan representation of the largest numeric value. weird but kind of cool. this shouldn't be a concern so you don't really need the "dirty" fix

Answer (score 0):

The `backgroundTimeRemaining` will return to you a `NSTimeInterval`, which is really just a `double` value.

I believe therefore, before it can register the time interval (it is returning to you the remaining time "too quickly") it will give you the maximum value that a double can represent.

```
The `double` data type gives a range of approximately 1.7E–308 to 1.7E+308 for type double.
```

...which is why you are getting that ridiculously lengthy value.

Happy coding! :)